# How can i open a .zip file in python?

Tags: python, zip, gzip

What are the changes that i have to make in this code in order to open a .zip file instead of .gz?

```
import gzip
embeddingsIn = gzip.open(embeddingsPath, "r") if embeddingsPath.endswith('.gz') else open(embeddingsPath, encoding="utf8")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You've tagged this question with the `zipfile` tag, which happens to be the name of the Python module that you would use.  Maybe read the documentation for that module?

Comment: Sorry i have removed that tag actually i am new to python so i dont have any idea about the syntax..

Comment: Well, start [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [gzip documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html), there's no simple or immediate way to do this:

> The GzipFile class reads and writes gzip-format files, [...]
>   Note that additional file formats which can be decompressed by the gzip and gunzip programs, such as those produced by compress and pack, are not supported by this module.

A possible workaround could be the use of the [zipfile module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html), which does indeed support `.zip` files, and put together a custom `my_open` function to open `.gz`, `.zip` and generic files

```
import zipfile, gzip

def my_open(path):
    if zipfile.is_zipfile(path):
        return zipfile.ZipFile(path)
    elif path.endswith('.gz'):
        return gzip.GzipFile(path)
    else:
        return open(path, encoding="utf8")
```

as a note, I used the `ZipFile` and `GzipFile` constructor because, according to their respective documentations ([zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile), [gzipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open)) they are both functionally equivalent to `gzip.open`, which is not implementd in `zipfile`.

Comment: Thanks for your response and can you please also guide me how the resulted file willbe passed to the variable embeddingsIn as mentioned above.

Comment: It should be as simple as `embeddingsIn = my_open("path/to/file")`

Comment: Thanks alot it must solve the issue. Now i got an other error related to the variable                                                                                                     for line in embeddingsIn:

TypeError: 'ZipFile' object is not iterable                                                             I will figure something out